# Photoshop settings reseting by themselves?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs5

I have had Photoshop CS 5.1 reset all of my settings several time without me telling it to do this!

I closed Photoshop and everything was fine. When I launched Photoshop the next time my setting were reset. I touched nothing when it was launching. I am a bit confused as how it reset when I did nothing to tell it to.

This is annoying due to the fact that I must go back into preferences and reset everything.

Any idea why this happened and what to do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sort of in response to your other question as well](https://superuser.com/questions/331290/dreamweaver-not-loading-workspace/331294#331294), I firstly would repeat the same warning and hope you are not using a pirate copy.

If you are not, it sounds like you have larger issues here and I would recommend a repair installation.

If this does not help, again, check for extensions but after this, I would perform diagnostics on your computer such as [memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) and a Scandisk to rule out issues with your computer.

If they find nothing, I would possibly try to contact Adobe support first as there may be an issue they are aware of.

If they can't help you, I would reinstall your operating system and install the Adobe suite from scratch.

Quite frankly, whilst it may be possible to help you by going through log files, I know from personal experience with Adobe suites how long this can take and you will most likely be better of in the long run going down this approach.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I am wondering about a larger issue. I will probably speak with support but I wanted to choose that as a last resort since Adobe support is well...lacking...Thanks for the information